# Is the volume of rotating $y=x^2$ around the y-axis equal to the volume of rotating half of the function $(x\geq0)$ around the y-axis?

Tags: integration, volume

We know that the volume of the shape formed by rotating $x=\sqrt{y}$ around the y-axis is $$\pi\int_{0}^{\infty} y dy$$
Is this equal to the volume of the shape formed by turning $y=x^2$ around the y-axis at $x=0$?

Comment: Your integral is convergent one?

Answer (score 1):

You should be cautious of $\infty$ as the upper bound because the integral here diverges.  If the upper bound is finite, then, yes, the two volumes are equal.

Comment: Your first variant of answer was equality between 2 infinity. Now, in second one, if you consider 2 integrals with finite 2 upper border, then their should be same, not only finite.

Comment: thanks! and i made a mistake in the integral, the integration variable is y, not x